# underfull \hbox in big landscape table

Tags: tables

I am experiencing several "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph" warnings in my big landscape-turned table. Unfortunately, I can't see where exactly the errors are in order to correct them. Any help is appreciated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,abstracton]{scrartcl}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}               %Zeichencodierung Text
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                     %Schriftsatz Dokument


%%Language settings
\usepackage[english]{babel}                  %ngerman for German
\usepackage{csquotes}                        %[babel,quotes=english]
%\usepackage{caption}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}}
%\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}   % only works when not using babel


%%Math, astro, chemical packages and options
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts,amsbsy,latexsym}
\usepackage{wasysym}                        %astronomical symbols
%\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}             %Chemie-Package
\providecommand{\e}[1]{\ensuremath{\times 10^{#1}}}

%\usepackage{dsfont}
%\usepackage{enumerate,url}


%%Paper adjustments
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{a4wide}                         %obsolete and replaced by geometry
\usepackage[a4paper,bottom=3.1cm]{geometry}  %also with command \geometry{options}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{subfigure}                      %obsolete
\usepackage{subcaption}                      %cannot be used with subfigure
%\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{textcomp, gensymb}    %textcomp before gensymb gets rid of the warnings "not defining \micro and \perthousand
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{array}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}                  %sets the section number depth
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}                     %sets the ToC depth
%\usepackage{verbatim}               %for multiline comments using \begin{} or \end{comment}


%% Control the fonts and formatting used in the table of contents.
%\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

%% Aesthetic spacing redefined
%\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{}
%\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.5ex}


%%Citations and Referencing
\usepackage[]{natbib}                        %replaced by biblatex (more flexible)
\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}
\bibliographystyle{authordate1}              %interferes with {natbib}-style-options; other nice ones: astron,authordate1,3
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}        %numbering the reference section
\settocbibname{References}                   %References->Bibliography: changed back
\usepackage{hyperref}                        %load after bib(la)tex
\usepackage{doi}

\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Impact data}
\label{Table:Impact data3}
\tiny
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.08\textwidth}p{0.14\textwidth}p{0.06\textwidth}p{0.09\textwidth}p{0.08\textwidth}p{0.10\textwidth}p{0.14\textwidth}p{0.11\textwidth}p{0.12\textwidth}p{0.14\textwidth}p{0.14\textwidth}p{0.13\textwidth}@{}}
    \cmidrule{1-12} \morecmidrules \cmidrule{1-12}
    \scriptsize{Group} & \scriptsize{Quartz sand grain size [mm]} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\scriptsize{Projectile}} & \scriptsize{Frequency [Hz]} & \scriptsize{Wheel circumference [mm]} & \scriptsize{Acceleration velocity of wheels [m/s]} & \scriptsize{Free fall time [s]} & \scriptsize{Impact velocity (computed) [m/s]} & \scriptsize{Impact velocity (light barriers) [m/s]} & \scriptsize{Kinetic energy [J]}} \\
    \cmidrule{3-5}
    & & \tiny{Material} & \tiny{Diameter [mm]} & \tiny{Weight [g]} & & & & & & & \\
    \midrule

    S & 0.1 - 0.45 & Glas & 5.5 $\pm$ 0.01 & 0.2 $\pm$ 0.1 & 50.1 $\pm$ 0.1 & 873 $\pm$ 4 & 43.7 $\pm$ 0.2 & 0.0244 $\pm$ 0.0004 & 44.0 $\pm$ 0.2 & 14.41 & 0.2 $\pm$ 0.1 \\

    \cmidrule{1-12} \morecmidrules \cmidrule{1-12}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape} 

\end{document}
```

One more question: I have several dozen lines in this table with the valus changing considerably, so that the $\pm$ sign moves around unaesthetically. What command is necessary in the above code to make the entries centred in the columns? This way the $\pm$ sign should be in the middle of the respective columns. Thanks

Comment: please always make your examples complete documents so people can run them, also note that if your `landscape` environment comes from `lscape` (you don't say, which is another reason for giving a complete document) then `\textwidth` is tehe original portrait `\textwidth` 9so the page head worls corectly) and the horizontal extent is `\linewidth` or `\hsize`, but as you note `p` columns are not best for numeric data.

Comment: I made a guess of a preamble, but then your example generates the error `! Missing { inserted.
<inserted text> 
                {
l.14     \cmidrule
` Please fix the example so that it runs without erro and demonstrates the problem

Comment: Adjusted the code: the whole preamble is now there to be sure not to miss anything.

Answer (score 1):

You do not really want justified text in such narrow columns, and size commands like `\tiny` and `\scriptsize` do not take an argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,pdflscape,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Impact data}
\label{Table:Impact data3}
\tiny
    \begin{tabular}{@{}
>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.08\textwidth}
>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.14\textwidth}
>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.06\textwidth}
>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.09\textwidth}
>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.08\textwidth}
>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.10\textwidth}
>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.14\textwidth}
>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.11\textwidth}
>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.12\textwidth}
>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.14\textwidth}
>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.14\textwidth}
>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.13\textwidth}@{}}
    \cmidrule{1-12} \morecmidrules \cmidrule{1-12}

\scriptsize Group & 
\scriptsize Quartz sand grain size [mm] & 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\scriptsize Projectile} & 
\scriptsize Frequency [Hz] & 
\scriptsize Wheel circumference [mm] & 
\scriptsize Acceleration velocity of wheels [m/s] & 
\scriptsize Free fall time [s] & 
\scriptsize Impact velocity (computed) [m/s] & 
\scriptsize Impact velocity (light barriers) [m/s] & 
\scriptsize Kinetic energy [J] \tabularnewline
    \cmidrule{3-5}
    & & 
\tiny Material & 
\tiny Diameter [mm]  & 
\tiny Weight [g]  & & & & & & & \\
    \midrule

    S & 0.1 - 0.45 & Glas & 5.5 $\pm$ 0.01 & 0.2 $\pm$ 0.1 & 50.1 $\pm$ 0.1 & 873 $\pm$ 4 & 43.7 $\pm$ 0.2 & 0.0244 $\pm$ 0.0004 & 44.0 $\pm$ 0.2 & 14.41 & 0.2 $\pm$ 0.1 \\

    \cmidrule{1-12} \morecmidrules \cmidrule{1-12}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run the code I get the following warnings

```
B: /Users/rudfaden/Desktop/test/test.tex:14 Underfull \hbox (badness 6775) in paragraph
B: /Users/rudfaden/Desktop/test/test.tex:14 Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
B: /Users/rudfaden/Desktop/test/test.tex:14 Overfull \hbox (1.0397pt too wide) in paragraph
B: /Users/rudfaden/Desktop/test/test.tex:14 Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
B: /Users/rudfaden/Desktop/test/test.tex:14 Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
B: /Users/rudfaden/Desktop/test/test.tex:14 Overfull \hbox (5.34167pt too wide) in paragraph
B: /Users/rudfaden/Desktop/test/test.tex:14 Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
B: /Users/rudfaden/Desktop/test/test.tex:14 Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
B: /Users/rudfaden/Desktop/test/test.tex:14 Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
B: /Users/rudfaden/Desktop/test/test.tex:14 Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
B: /Users/rudfaden/Desktop/test/test.tex:14 Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
B: /Users/rudfaden/Desktop/test/test.tex:14 Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
B: /Users/rudfaden/Desktop/test/test.tex:14 Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
B: /Users/rudfaden/Desktop/test/test.tex:14 Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
B: /Users/rudfaden/Desktop/test/test.tex:14 Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
B: /Users/rudfaden/Desktop/test/test.tex:16 Overfull \hbox (4.55118pt too wide) in paragraph
B: /Users/rudfaden/Desktop/test/test.tex:16 Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
B: /Users/rudfaden/Desktop/test/test.tex:16 Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
B: /Users/rudfaden/Desktop/test/test.tex:19 Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
B: /Users/rudfaden/Desktop/test/test.tex:12 Overfull \hbox (27.05295pt too wide) in paragraph
```

`underfull \hbox` is warning that LaTeX cannot stretch the line wide enough to fit, without making the spacing bigger than its currently permitted maximum. An `overfull \hbox` means that there is a hyphenation or justification problem: moving the last word on the line to the next line would make the spaces in the line wider than the current limit

Looking at the errors, they are producd by line 14, which is the header row in my document. So the problem is that you are kramming to much space into the headers and latex is warning you about it. But note that it is just a warning. If you a happy with the result, there is no reason to change them. However, I would split the table in two.